# Is a good way to return a __weak var?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
@interface SomeClass {
...
__weak SomeType* ivar;
}
- (SomeType*) getVar;

@implementation SomeClass
...
// set ivar some value
- (void) someFunc {
...
ivar = someVar;
}

- (SomeType*) getVar{
 return ivar;
}
@end
```

And I want return ivar, and if someVar is nil at sometimes then the ival is nil, that is the reason to use weak.Is this code right? 
Or is the following code right?

```
 @interface SomeClass
 @property(weak,readonly) SomeType* ivar;
 @end   

 @implementation SomeClass
    ...
    // set ivar some value
    - (void) someFunc {
    ...
    _ivar = someVar;
    }

 @end
```

Comment: why would you need a `__weak` ivar?

Comment: store and return some object.

Comment: isn't a regular ivar gets done your job? ivars are by default `__strong` variables. Why would you need it to be `__weak`?  (unless you want to break a retain cycle)

Comment: Oh , maybe someVar will be nil at sometimes, so I need to know  ivar is nil or not, so I use weak.

Comment: what's the benefit of using `__weak` to know if your ivar is nil? you can simply check for nil with a `__strong` ivar as well. Using `__weak` will get you into more trouble if you are not exactly sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if in your `someFunc` no one else hold a strong reference to `someVar` after method finishes, your `ivar` no longer posses value you have assigned to it. You'll lose it.

Better really use property. But it should be `readwrite`, at least inside of your implementation, so that you will somehow retain values assigned to `ivar`

Comment: Can you explain why the value would be lost?  Changing from weak to strong won't lose the value, will it?

Comment: __weak means not to retain value. __strong will retain. Moment, when retain counter of object is 0, it is erased

Comment: But the OP is holding it as weak and returning it as strong, so it will be lost before the getter method is called anyway.  Your answer makes little sense at all.

Comment: No one returns weak or strong. Method returns reference to some object. If you will assign returned value to strong-holding variable, that object's retain counter increased, other way it will not. 
So, if you want to have weak reference to object, you need some one to hold strong reference to that object - thats what I'm saying in my answer

Comment: Not true; the OP would need to use `- (__weak SomeType*) getVar{` in order to keep the reference weak; as he has it, it's converted to a strong reference.